# don't receive notifications on android 2.2 using GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, google-play-services

I'm using the new GoogleCloudMessaging API (from Play Services library, because old Google cloud messaging for android was deprecated) in my project and I have some bugs. When I send messages from my server to all registered devices, my nexus 4 (android 4.4)  receives the notification messages, but my Samsung Galaxy Ace doesn't receive them, That's strange, because there are no exceptions or crashes of my project.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="ru.test"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

        <receiver
           android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
           android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
              <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                 <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                 <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
              </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="ru.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String regId = intent.getExtras().getString("registration_id");
           if(regId != null && !regId.equals("")) {
              /* Do what ever you want with the regId eg. send it to your server */

               Log.d(MainActivity.tag, "onReceive " + regId);
           }

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
```

}

GcmIntentService.java

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";

    String title = "";
    String message = "";
    String subtext = "";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle

             title = extras.getString("title");
             message = extras.getString("message");
             subtext = extras.getString("subtext");


            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */ 
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                message = "Send error";
                sendNotification(title, message, subtext);
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {             
                message = "Deleted messages on server";
                sendNotification(title, message, subtext);
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification(title, message, subtext);
                Log.d(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String title, String message, String subtext) {



        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigxtstyle =
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();          
                bigxtstyle.bigText(message);               

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_large))
                .setTicker(message)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)
                //.setContentInfo("Content info")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSubText(subtext)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        mNotificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());



    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your manifest and client code if you want an answer instead of guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main package name is `ru.test`, but in the GCM permissions you specified `com.example.gcm` as the package name. That's why it doesn't work in 2.x Android version (for some reason this mismatch doesn't affect 4.x versions).

The following changes will solve your problem:

```
<permission android:name="ru.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ru.test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <receiver
       android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
             <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
             <category android:name="ru.test" />
          </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I also suggest that you change your `minSdkVersion` from 7 to 8, since GCM is not supported in API level 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Play application is updated in Galaxy Ace? Probably this is the problem.

Another hypothesis would not be logged into any google account on the device. to receive notifications in versions prior to 4.0.4 is mandatory to be logged in at least one regard.